# SQL query for in between data in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please give me right answer for this question

This is the table `time_names` and its structure:

```
time_id    time_name
-------    ----------
  1        5:00 AM
  2        5:15 AM
  3        5:30 AM
  4        5:45 AM
  5        6:00 AM
  6        6:15 AM
 ...       .....
 ...       .....
 70        10:15 PM
 71        10:30 PM
 72        10:45 PM
 73        11:00 PM
 74        11:15 PM
 75        11:30 PM
 76        11:45 PM
```

`time_id` is `INT`, `time_name` is `varchar` datatype.

Here I want show only `8:30 AM` to `11:00 PM` between all data

Please give me any query

Comment: Are `time_id` and `time_name` two columns of the same table? Or two separate tables?? Not clear at all ..... also: **SHOW US YOUR EFFORT!** We'll be glad to help - but SO is not a *gimme-ze-codez* kind of code-writing service....

Comment: @marc_s totally agree. Also I think the question "Please give me any query" is some kind of funny :)

Comment: Thank u for editing and here both are same table time_names

Comment: @RomanPekar: *give me any query* but at the same time *give me right answer* !! That makes it kinda tricky! :-)

Comment: I am trying select *from time_names where time_name between ('8:30 Am 'and '11:00 Pm')

Comment: Marc_s i want between time_name not Time_id

Comment: ok ok i am using sql 2008 and Time_id is int and Time_name is varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on SQL Server 2008, you can simply cast the `time_name` to a `TIME` datatype:

```
SELECT time_id, time_name
FROM dbo.time_names
WHERE CAST(time_name AS TIME) BETWEEN '08:30 AM' AND '11:00 PM'
```

But seriously: if you store a time value - ***WHY*** aren't you using the appropriate `TIME` datatype for it??

Comment: Isn't it safer to explicitly specify format for conversion? like `convert(time, time_name, 109)`

Answer (score 1):

`select time_name between` will not work, because it's string comparison. You have to use `time_id` or convert time, for example like this

```
select *
from time_names
where convert(nvarchar(8), convert(datetime, time_name, 109), 108) between '08:30' and '23:00'
```

Here I'm converting time from string to real date time and then converting it into 24 hours format, so you can use string compare.
you also can use `time` type

```
select *
from time_names
where convert(time, time_name, 109) between '08:30' and '23:00'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

I also have to say that this table design looks really bad. You have to store date and time in the columns with apropriate types.

Comment: Hoo thanks but u one alos working in my side some changes are there thanks Roman Pekar

Answer (score 0):

I´m not a SQL user but try to convert the 'time_name'  to DateTime data type and use a select between DateTime1 AND DateTime2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
CREATE table #Time(
time_id int PRIMARY key,
time_name varchar(255))
INSERT INTO #Time values(1, '5:00 AM')
INSERT INTO #Time values(2, '5:15 AM')
INSERT INTO #Time values(3, '5:30 AM')
INSERT INTO #Time values(4, '5:45 AM')
INSERT INTO #Time values(5, '6:00 AM')
INSERT INTO #Time values(6, '6:15 AM')
INSERT INTO #Time values(7, '6:30 AM')
INSERT INTO #Time values(8, '6:45 AM')

select * from #Time
where CAST(time_name as datetime) between CAST('5:30 AM' as datetime) and CAST('6:00    AM' as datetime)


DROP TABLE #Time
```

Comment: Actually - you can use `CAST(... AS TIME)` (no need for `DATETIME`) in SQL Server 2008 - and you don't need to cast the string literals representing the time border values - T-SQL will do thsi automatically for you

Comment: Yes. We can use following query instead. (select * from #Time
where CAST(time_name as datetime) between '5:30 AM'  and '6:00 AM')